# Joi validation without Hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

I am using Joi to validate the schema and I are not using Hapi.

I am writing a test case where my joi schema should return an error. Below is my schema

```
const testSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  name: Joi.string().required(),
  data: Joi.array().min(1).max(8).required(),
});
```

My current payload

```
const currentPayload = {
  data: ['1', '2'],
};
```

and my simple validation is

```
try {
  const result = Joi.validate(currentPayload, testSchema);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Now, this `err` just contains a canned message without details. To get detailed message, I need to use `failAction` as described [here](https://github.com/hapijs/glue/issues/113)

What I have understood so far is that `failAction` is hapi function and not joi.

Any ideas how can I get detailed error message to work

Edit:

Here is how the `err` object looks like

[image]

Comment: The 'result' constant should have the message.

Comment: It does not contain detail. Just a generic message. Added the screenshot in the question

Comment: @NickLeBlanc You were right. I had made a stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

This is really embarrassing. This error gets thrown if the schema mentioned in the `Joi.validate` in invalid. In my case it was `undefined` as I was referencing it incorrectly from another file :(

the good part is now I know when Joi will throw an exception :)